# How to declare the location of Emacs's init file as a variable

Tags: emacs, cross-platform

I use Emacs across a few computers (Linux and Windows boxes) with my .emacs.d synced via ownCloud: .emacs (in ~ or Appdata) just loads {ownCloud directory}/.emacs.d/init.el.

My question is, how do I get that path to the init.el as variable dependent on the OS/username.

For example, the README on the [Zenburn theme](https://github.com/bbatsov/zenburn-emacs) requires your init includes

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
```

But as the path from my home directory and .emacs.d varies between machines, this won't work.
I was thinking of something like this to remedy it:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "{THE DIRECTORY THAT CONTAINS THIS INIT FILE}/themes/")
```

Can this be done? I'm only a fortnight's into using Emacs, so don't bite too hard :P

Comment: Oh, and you might want to clarify your question. Your title is different from the body. (Besides, the location of the init file already is a variable)

Comment: Thanks guys. For the example of the second question (body), it turns out I needed to define user-emacs-directory in the individual systems' .emacs and then use something to the effect of `(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path (concat user-emacs-directory "themes/"))` in the synced init file to allow for the themes folder. Not exactly elegant, but it works. Oh, sorry about the lack of clarity of the question(s), it was in the wee hours. Thanks to @BruceConnor for the info on how I'd go about modulising my init file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `system-type` determines between Linux and Windows machines. The variable `user-login-name` is self explanatory. I use these to load different files depending on which machine I'm in.

```
(if (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
   (when (string= user-login-name "home user name")
     (load-file "/path/to/file"))
   (when (string= user-login-name "work user name")
     (load-file "/path/to/other-file")))
```

Honestly though, this is more appropriate for miscellaneous configurations. I wouldn't recommend using this to change your emacs directory location.

Instead, create symlinks on each machine in order to *pretend* your emacs directory is in the standard place. (I've been doing this on 4 different machines for a couple of years now, and it's going well).

---

Finally, to answer your last question. The init file already is a variable, and its name is `user-init-file`. To extract the directory it's located in just do

```
 (file-name-directory user-init-file)
```

Comment: If your usernames are identical you can also query environment variables with `(getenv "variable name")`, which should be enough to distinguish any two systems.

Answer (score 2):

There is `user-emacs-directory` variable.